# Codeigniter simple validation callback not working

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

UPDATED

I'm creating a [codeigniter callback](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) for validating an input where users enter programming tags for example `php, js, jquery`. Values are separated by commas.

I want to show a message if you enter duplicate tags for example `php, jquery, php, js` where `php` would be the duplicate.

First in my controller I set the validation rules for the 'user_tags` input

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_tags', 'User Tags', 'callback_user_tags_dublicates', 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]|regex_match[/^[a-z,0-9+# ]+$/i]');
```

Then the callback

```
<?php function user_tags_dublicates($str)
        {
            $val = $str; //the input value (all the CSV)
            $tags = str_getcsv($val); //creates an array of the CSV
            if(count($tags) != count(array_unique($tags))) //if array not equal to unique array it contains duplicates
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('user_tags', 'The %s field can not have duplicate tags.');
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        } ?>
```

and finally in the view I show my error.

```
<?php echo form_error('user_tags'); ?>
```

When I enter duplicate tags I get

`Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tested the function in a static page without validation rules and it works.

Comment: Try using "<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your error message for `user_tags` inside your `user_tags_dublicates()` function

```
   $this->form_validation->set_message('user_tags', 'The %s field can not have duplicate tags.');
```

Comment: thanks I fixed and I get `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.`

Comment: nvm, I actually had to add'_dublicates' when setting the error message

Comment: move `set_message` outside the function. for example place it under your `set_rules()` statements

Answer (score 1):

This might sound stoopid but have you checked:

```
$tags = str_getcsv($val); //creates an array of the CSV
```

actually returns the tags properly?

Comment: yes it creates an array. I have tested the entire function without the validation rules and it works